# How to do signIn and signUp of AWS Amplify in postman

Tags: aws-amplify, amplifyjs

I'm using aws-amplify in react native application. I am trying to create a postman collection of my app and I am unable to figure out what are the endpoints for SignIn, signUp and what data need to send in postman. I could not find any documentation related to it as well. Please guide me.